# Java Reading Words from a file with apostrophies and hypens and counting them as 2 words

Tags: java, text-files, java.util.scanner, words

I am writing a program that will read two files in from the command line and find how many words in each .txt file. I have got my code to work, however I need it to count each apostrophe as 2 words and each hyphen as two words. Something like this e.g., John's will become two separate words "john" and "s" and Tick-Tock will become "tick" and "tock"). I cannot use util.regex also. Here is my code"

```
private void readFile(){
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){

            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] wordOfLine = line.split("\\W");
            lineNum++;//accumulate line

            //counts all words 
            for (String word : wordOfLine){

                if (word.equals("") || !(isWord(word)))
                    continue;
                words.add(word.toLowerCase());
                if (wordNum + 1 > wordNum){//in case of overflow
                    wordNum++;//accumulate word
                }

                else
                    throw new Error(" word number overflow!");

            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        throw new Error("cannot find file!");
    } finally{
        if (scanner != null)
            scanner.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Test for wordNum "+wordNum); 

}


//check if text is word
private boolean isWord(String text) {
    return text.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
}
```

For example here is my test end results:

Test for wordNum 54

Test for wordNum 49516

File f1: 9 lines, 54 words, 38 distinct words

File f2: 4666 lines, 49516 words, 5103 distinct words

f1 matches fine with results expected 
but f2 needs to be like this

File f2: 4666 lines, 49714 words, 5216 distinct words

here is some of the document for f2 
THE PRINCE

by Nicolo Machiavelli

Translated by W. K. Marriott

Nicolo Machiavelli, born at Florence on 3rd May 1469. From 1494 to 1512
held an official post at Florence which included diplomatic missions to
various European courts. Imprisoned in Florence, 1512; later exiled and
returned to San Casciano. Died at Florence on 22nd June 1527.

INTRODUCTION

Nicolo Machiavelli was born at Florence on 3rd May 1469. He was the
second son of Bernardo di Nicolo Machiavelli, a lawyer of some repute,
and of Bartolommea di Stefano Nelli, his wife. Both parents were members
of the old Florentine nobility.

Comment: Use the `useDelimiter()` method of the `Scanner` class to set the delimiter used to separate words and then use the `next()` and `hasNext()` methods to loop through the scanner and get the words.

Comment: Why don't you just split on `\P{Alpha}+`?

Comment: String.split will just call Pattern.compile(regex).split() except for simple one char patterns. Seems odd that you can use this but not the java.util.regex package directly?

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] tokens = "abc-def".split("((?<=-)|(?=-))");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[abc, -, def]
```

Comment: That doesn't work this is the results: Test for wordNum 0
Test for wordNum 33
File merchant.txt: 9 lines, 0 words, 0 distinct words
File theprince.txt: 4666 lines, 33 words, 26 distinct words
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: one of the input is empty, cannot calculate distance!
 at FileAdapter.distance(FileAdapter.java:163)
 at ComputeDistanceBetween.main(ComputeDistanceBetween.java:30)

Comment: The above is only for hyphens, you will have to implement it for "'s".